# CMake install target when using FetchContent and add_subdirectory

Tags: linux, cmake

My CMake project has a top directory that includes subdirectories with `add_subdirectory`. In some subdirectories, the CMakeLists.txt file fetches repositories with `FetchContent`, and others are just subdirectories in my repository.

How do I make an appropriate `install` target with CMake that will install everything in the subdirectories' install targets? I don't have an explicit `install` statement in my top-level CMakeLists.txt because the top level doesn't build anything, it only adds the subdirectories. When I build everything into a common build directory and do `make install` or `cmake --install`, it copies everything in the `_deps` folder to `/usr/local`, which is inappropriate, and then chokes because it can't find a particular .pc file, which I don't believe I need to install.

I'd also appreciate a general explanation of how CMake handles install targets in this kind of nested-directory situation.

In case it's relevant, I'm building for ARM in an emulator with schroot on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: "How do I make an appropriate install target with CMake that will install everything in the subdirectories' install targets?" - CMake does that by default. If it is not your case and "it copies everything in the `_deps` folder to `/usr/local`", then there is something specific with your project or subprojects.

Comment: I've run into the same question myself, but in my case my top-level does do an install command and is complaining that `install(EXPORT ...) includes target "A" which requires target "B" that is not in any export set`. Typical solutions don't solve it since `FetchContent` pulls things in using an alias. Hoping your question gets an answer...

Comment: @Riddick "FetchContent pulls things in using an alias"... what?